# Laravel - Return ID to database when selecting a name from dropdown

Tags: laravel

I have a student notes view where a teacher can enter notes for a specific student. On this view there is a dropdown box for the students name and a text field for the note. I currently am able to view the students names from the students table but am unsure how to return the ID number linked to the name (The student ID) to the notes table?

**Notes View:**

```
@section('content')
<section>
    <h1>Student Notes</h1>
    <form action="{{ route('notes.store') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-col">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="student_name">Student Name:</label>
                <select id="student_name" name="student_name" required>
                <option value="">--- Select Name ---</option>
                    @foreach ($student as $key => $value)
                    <option value="{{ $key }} "> {{ $value->first_name}} {{ $value->last_name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-col">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="note">Notes:</label>
                <textarea id="note" name="note" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Enter notes here"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
@endsection
```

**Notes Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Note;
use App\Models\Student;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NotesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        
        $student=Student::all();
        //return $student;
        return view('pages.notes.Notes', ['student'=>$student]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Note::create($request->all());
        return redirect('notes');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Note  $note
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Note $note)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Note  $note
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Note $note)
    {
        return view('pages.notes.Notes_edit', compact('note'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Note  $note
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $notes = Note::query();
        if ($notes->where('id', $id)->exists()) {
            $note = $notes->find($id);
            $note->student_name = is_null($request->student_name) ? $note->student_name : $request->student_name;
            $note->note = is_null($request->note) ? $note->note : $request->note;
            $note->save();
            return redirect('notes');
    }
}

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Note  $note
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $notes = Note::query();
        if($notes->where('id', $id)->exists()) {
            $note = $notes->find($id);
            $note->delete($id);
            return redirect('notes');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should us your either or Data Table,
Example:
If you does have iStudentID , iStudentFName, iStudentLName in your Data Model,
you could call the ID with code as below:

```
@foreach ($student as $value)
     option value="{{ $value->iStudentID }} "> {{ $value->iStudentFName}} {{ $value->iStudentLName}}</option>
@endforeach
```